# Sum of subsequences

Tags: algorithm

Consider the first integer is A, A[i] equals i-th digit of A (0-based indexing, from right to left) and the second integer is B , B[i] equals to i-th digit of B (0-based indexing, from right to left).

The *lucky sum* of A and B is equal to C, C[i] = max(A[i], B[i]). If i is greater than or equal to size of integer, the i-th digit is equal to 0.

For example,

1. the lucky sum of 47 and 729 is

   > ```
   > max(7,9)=9
   > max(4,2)=4
   > max(0,7)=7
   > answer = 749
   > ```
2. Similarly, the lucky sum of W = (74, 92, 477)

   > ```
   > max(4,2) = 4
   > max(7,9) = 9
   > Lucky sum of 74,92 = 94
   > Lucky sum of W=(Lucky sum of (94,477))
   > ```

   which is

   > ```
   > max(4,7)=7
   > max(9,7)=9
   > max(0,4)=4
   > ```

So the lucky sum of w is=497.

***The task:*** we are given an array  W, containing n (1<=n<=50) integers.

We have to **find a number of non-empty subsequences of W such that the lucky sum of integers in that subsequences is a *lucky number*** (*lucky numbers* are positive integers whose decimal representation contains only the lucky digits 4 and 7. For example, numbers 47, 744, 4 are lucky and 5, 17, 467 are not.).

Constraint: 0 < W[i] < 1e9

Examples:

1. W = {4,7}: answer = 3
2. W = {43, 87 ,44}: answer = 2

Can this problem be solved by **dynamic programming?**

How this problem can be solved efficiently in C++ ?

Comment: Assume you have number of lucky sum in first n-1 numbers in W, now adding last number to sequence just causes to check if it has lucky sum with first n-1 numbers or not, So it's O(n^2) and because n<= 50, it's fast enough. (Am I wrong?)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri the first n-1 numbers may generate lots of different lucky numbers, how do you determine which sub-set to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i can think of(unfinished yet):

Uses **DP** with **bit mask**. we now represent a number in the following way: every bit is categorized into five kinds:

1. (0)       ->  0
2. (1,2,3)   ->  1
3. (4)       ->  2
4. (5,6)     ->  3
5. (7)       ->  4
6. (8,9)     ->  -1

As we can easily see, whenever a bit is 8 or 9, it can never be added into a valid solution. now we represent the number with bit-mask, which takes `5^8`.

So we let `f[i][s]` denotes the total ways we can choose the subset from the `first i numbers` to make out the number `whose bit-mask is s`.

Here is the code i just wrote again.....
Three things remains:

1. use `__int64` or `long long` instead of `int` for `f[][]`.
2. use `queue` to accelerate enumeration for there are a lot of impossible status(i.e. f[][s]==0) if we enumerate with `for (i = 0;i < MAXS;i++)`.
3. use f[0..1][MAXS] to reduce memory cost.

The sample code:

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

#define MAXN 51
#define MAXS 390625 //5^8

using namespace std;

const int exp[] = {1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, 15625, 78125, 390625};
int n;
int w[MAXN];
struct node{
    int i;
    int stat;
    node(int x, int y):i(x),stat(y){}
};
queue<node> q;
__int64 f[MAXN][MAXS];
bool inq[MAXN][MAXS];

int main(){
    //freopen("test.txt","r",stdin);
    memset(f,0,sizeof(f));
    memset(inq,0,sizeof(inq));
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) scanf("%d",&w[i]);
    while (!q.empty()) q.pop();
    f[0][0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
        for (int j = 0;j < MAXS;j++)
            if (f[i][j] > 0){
                f[i + 1][j] += f[i][j];
                int stat = j;
                int loc = 0;
                int k = 0;
                for (int p = w[i];p > 0;p /= 10){
                    k = p % 10;
                    if (k <= 0) k = 0;
                        else if (k <= 3) k = 1;
                            else if (k <= 4) k = 2;
                                else if (k <= 6) k = 3;
                                    else if (k <= 7) k = 4;
                                        else k = -1;
                    if (k < 0) break;
                    int bit = stat % exp[loc + 1] / exp[loc];
                    if (k < bit) k = bit;
                    stat = stat - (bit - k) * exp[loc];
                    loc++;
                }
                if (k < 0) continue;
                f[i + 1][stat] += f[i][j];
            }
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i < MAXS;i++){
        bool flag = false;
        for (int loc = 7;loc >= 0;loc--){
            int bit = i % exp[loc + 1] / exp[loc];
            if (bit > 0) flag = true;
            if (flag == true && (bit != 2 && bit != 4)){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == true) ans += f[n][i];
    }
    printf("%d\n",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every bit of the answer is independent. So update them separately and the whole algorithm takes `O(n*log10(w))`

Here's the code i just wrote:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

#define MAXL 15

using namespace std;

int n;
int ans[MAXL];

int main(){
    int i,j,w;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    memset(ans,0,sizeof(ans));
    while (n--){
        scanf("%d",&w);
        i = 0;
        while (w>0){
            j = w % 10;
            ans[i] = max(ans[i], j);
            i++;
            w /= 10;
        }
    }
    bool flag = false;
    for (i=MAXL-1;i>=0;i--){
        if (ans[i] > 0) flag = true;
        if (flag) printf("%d",ans[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This just computes the lucky sum of a sequence of numbers. The actual question is more complicated than that.

Comment: @svick i realized that, sorry for the misunderstanding, i am now reconsidering this problem.